# Prevent 'Save Picture As' in Sharepoint 2010 Picture Library

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to set up a Picture Library in SharePoint 2010 where I can make images available to people with the 'View Only' permission, and prevent them from downloading the images.

The SharePoint 'Actions->Download' option is not available to them, however they can still view the picture in full size and right click->Save Picture As to download it.

Is there any way of preventing / disabling this?

Answer (score 0):

An image in a web browser has already been downloaded to the person's computer. Browsers are configured to allow users to save an image an another location other than the temporary director to which the file was saved.  To prevent users from downloading the image, you would need to send them something other than the image. The only way I can think of doing so is to use Silverlight or Flash to show the user the image on a page somewhere.  SharePoint has an Image Viewer web part that could do this.

Of course by doing this, you would need to change the way the user accesses the picture library, possibly by setting up a calculated or hyperlink field that creates the link to the page with the embedded image viewer. The page would need a filter of some sort so it knows what image you want to view and a workflow would need to be set up that populates the hyperlink field.

Comment: One trick that people use is to hook the right mouse click using javascript.  You can get around this, but it is effective for most users.

Comment: I agree, disabling right click is another way.  It would only work, of course, if you're looking at a page on which JavaScript can be placed. If the user is looking directly at the image (i.e. http://somesite/someimage.jpg), there's no way to prevent the user from saving the image.  My method isn't fool proof, but it does use SharePoint functionality.